# What is a dispersion relation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, wave-packets

What exactly is a dispersion relation?

It shows up all the time in my physics classes and I never fully understood its meaning.

Currently I am working on the linear chain model in crytsallography and after doing all the work of using F=ma and doing an ansatz with complex waves, all that shows up and seems to be of general interest is the following dispersion relation:

$$\omega=2\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\left\vert{\sin\frac{ka}{2}}\right\vert$$

I don't care that much for the specific problem at hand, I'd rather like to know why expressions like these show up so often and how I should read them?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this belongs rather to a physics forum, but as you see it is an equation linking $\omega$ and $k$, thus saying which planar waves are possible in your medium, and therefore also describing all the possible waves (as linear combinations of planar ones; more precisely one should allow integrals in place of sums in these linear combinations). You need a wave problem which is translation-invariant both in time and in space (in your case you only have translations preserving the lattice I guess, but it's ok).

Comment: Regarding choice of forum: I think OP wants the term “dispersion relation” explained in the style of a mathematician rather than in the style of a physicist. OP has already read physics explanations and is looking for something more precise — this is where an answer from a *mathematician* can be very helpful. I found MathWonk’s answer to be clear and illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Many physical effects are modeled by systems of linear partial differential equations that have certain elementary plane-wave solutions in space-time: solutions of the form $ e^{i \vec k \cdot\vec x+\omega t}$. (This is especially true of partial differential equations that have constant coefficients.)  Often there are  boundary conditions  or other compatibility conditions that impose one or more constraints on $\omega$ and $\vec k$. These are the **dispersion relations**.

Additional comments. One can visualize each such constraining relation  as defining a surface  in the frequency domain $(\vec k, \omega)$ that is dual to space-time.  The intersection of all these constraints defines a special subset $S$ in that dual space. An arbitrary  superposition of such plane-wave solutions selected from $S$ is also a solution (by linearity).
Thus one is led to consider  expressions such as $$(1)\qquad I(\vec x, t)=\int_{(\vec k, \omega)\in S} a(\vec k, \omega)  e^{ i\vec k \cdot \vec x + \omega t}$$  which are  (at least formally) solutions of the PDE system.
Typically the set $S$ is a smooth or piecewise smooth  curved submanifold, and then one can give a rigorous definition of such  superposition integrals.

Moreover, by approximating the curved object $S$ by an osculating polynomial approximation, one can sometimes construct explicit analytical approximations to  true solutions that are asymptotically good in certain regimes (e.g. far-field regions in $(x,t)$ space).

To understand how the geometry of $S$ affects the integral (1) , it might be helpful to mentally transpose the roles of space-time and its dual space $(\vec k, \omega)$ when visualizing the comment that follows.

We can interpret (1) as the how much illumination from a plane wave  directed along $<\vec x,t>$ is absorbed by the target surface $S$.
Then we see that  the net contribution to the integral  (1) when   a very high-frequency plane wave arriving from the direction $<x,t>$ encounters a small surface patch $\Delta S$  will generally be small (because high-frequency oscillations passing through $S$ mostly self-cancel.) The exception to this principle occurs when the plane wave-fronts hit $\Delta S$ "broadside". That is the direction $<x,t>$ is a normal vector to the patch $ \Delta S$. This is a so-called stationary phase condition, and is the basis for many asymptotic approximations in the far-field regions.

The modern theory of oscillatory integral operators has been built to create a rigorous foundation for such intuitive principles.